# htaccess rewrite XML sitemap and user friendly sitemap

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two scripts:

- xmlsitemap.php (Google XML sitemap)
- sitemap.php (GUI user friendly sitemap)

I want to achieve this with rewrite rules:

**Rewrite to site.com/sitemap.php**
site.com/sitemap
site.com/sitemap/

**Rewrite to site.com/xmlsitemap.php**
site.com/sitemap.xml

Here is what I have tried. The problem is it's rewriting sitemap.xml to sitemap.php (GUI).

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule sitemap.xml xmlsitemap.php
RewriteRule sitemap sitemap.php

# also tried using [L] option on both
```

Comment: What does not work? Have you started with a single rewrite for a single script and you got it to work?

Comment: It rewrites site.com/sitemap.xml to sitemap.php which is wrong. sitemap.xml should rewrite to xmlsitemap.php. Both rules work when the other is commented out, the problem is they don't work together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, re-add the `[L]` flag. Second, if one rule supersedes the other, check your rewrite rules regex to make them better matching, like the whole request:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ xmlsitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ sitemap.php [L]
```

The `L` flag will prevent to run additional rules if one already matched (but still can trigger an internal redirect, see as well the [END flag instead of the L flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12106419/367456)).

Comment: Thanks, works. I've just added another rule with a trailing / to accomodate site.com/sitemap/