# Mod_Rewrite unexpected behavior L flag

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

my web application structure is:

```
/var/www/myapp/
    - www/
        - index.php
        - css.php
        - .htaccess
```

the virtual host is configured as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/www
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        <Directory /var/www/myapp/www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In /var/www/myapp/www/.htaccess there is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule css css.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule .* index.php
</IfModule>
```

Now, if I call www.example.org I'm correctly redirected to index.php, but if I call www.example.org/css I'm still redirected always to index.php.

If I drop the line "RewriteRule .* index.php" and then call www.example.org/css, I'm correctly redirected to css.php.

What's wrong?
Thanks all very much

======== EDIT =========

```
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b7080058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] add path info postfix: /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/DEV_2 -> /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/DEV_2/css/example1/test.css
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b7080058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/DEV_2/css/example1/test.css -> DEV_2/css/example1/test.css
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b7080058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] applying pattern '^(DEV|TEST|PROD)\_[0-9]+\/(css|js|image|static)\/(.+)$' to uri 'DEV_2/css/example1/test.css'
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b7080058/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] rewrite 'DEV_2/css/example1/test.css' -> 'css/example1/test.css'
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b7080058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] add per-dir prefix: css/example1/test.css -> /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/css/example1/test.css
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b7080058/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/ with /
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b7080058/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/css/example1/test.css -> css/example1/test.css
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b7080058/initial] (4) add subst prefix: css/example1/test.css -> /css/example1/test.css
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b7080058/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] internal redirect with /css/example1/test.css [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b63188e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/css/example1/test.css -> css/example1/test.css
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b63188e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] applying pattern '^(DEV|TEST|PROD)\_[0-9]+\/(css|js|image|static)\/(.+)$' to uri 'css/example1/test.css'
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b63188e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/css/example1/test.css -> css/example1/test.css
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b63188e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'css/example1/test.css'
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b63188e8/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] rewrite 'css/example1/test.css' -> 'index.php'
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b63188e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/index.php
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b63188e8/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/ with /
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b63188e8/initial/redir#1] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/index.php -> index.php
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b63188e8/initial/redir#1] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b63188e8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b6310db8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/index.php -> index.php
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b6310db8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] applying pattern '^(DEV|TEST|PROD)\_[0-9]+\/(css|js|image|static)\/(.+)$' to uri 'index.php'
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b6310db8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/index.php -> index.php
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b6310db8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php'
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b6310db8/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] rewrite 'index.php' -> 'index.php'
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b6310db8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/index.php
192.168.1.8 - - [14/Jul/2012:19:07:21 +0200] [www.example.org/sid#b747b6c0][rid#b6310db8/initial/redir#2] (1) [perdir /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: /var/www/sviluppo/mattia_dev/example/www/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

Seems that a first redirect occurs but the mod_rewrite doesn't stop causing an internal redirect. Then, the changed url, is passed to mod_rewrite another time and a second redirect occured but now matching the second rule.

I can't understand it because I've placed the [L] flag just to ensure that the mod_rewrite stops.

Thanks another time

Comment: This is interesting. The settings look okay, and I tried it on my system and it works. Maybe you might want to turn on logging for rewrites to see what exactly gets rewritten: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: I've edited the message, you will find a log. Just focus on the INTERNAL REDIRECT :-)

Comment: see @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811081/htaccess-stop-internal-redirect

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are missing an important fact about the [`L` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l):

> It is therefore important, if you are using [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directives in one of these [`.htaccess`, `<Directory>`] contexts, that **you take explicit steps to avoid rules looping, and not count solely on the [L] flag to terminate execution of a series** of rules

*From: [L|last (Flag)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l); bold by me*

That means, only by using the `L` does not have your desired effect to prevent the interal redirect. The `INTERNAL REDIRECT` happens here because it must happen, you have specified it with your `.htaccess` configuration. The `L` flag is *not* the right flag to prevent the `INTERNAL REDIRECT`.

Let's look closer at your question and what actually happens:

> I can't understand it because I've placed the [L] flag just to ensure that the mod_rewrite stops.

Is just that you have the wrong undestanding of the `L` flag. It will only stop for the current rewriting, meaning, the `RewriteRule` directives beneath it are not going to be processed in the current round (the inner loop).

If the URI changed `L` will re-inject into the the next round (the outer loop) as the following [technical details flowchart](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html) shows:

[image: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html]

To highlight where the `L` flag kicks in and where the `INTERNAL REDIRECT` happens, this is the same graphic with some annotations for your specfic (first) URI rewrite:

[image]

It shows that the `L` flag only exits the inner loop but if the URI has been rewritten (changed) - as in your case - the outer loop takes care that the changed URI will be passed *again* to all your rewrite rules.

Instead you might want to formulate a condition as the following example from that part of the manual shows:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?req=$1 [L,PT]
```

([`PT` has it's own manual entry](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt), is is more or less not part of the solution, just noting because I quoted the example as-is)

What you actually want to use is the `END` flag:

```
RewriteRule css css.php [END,NC]
```

However contact your system administrator if you have the needed apache version for it (Available in 2.3.9 and later). If not, you need to operate with [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It was a bit hard to describe in words, so I thought with the graphics this should be better.

Comment: Excellent answer, I love the diagrams!

Comment: best illustration of mod_rewrite ever!

Comment: I completely agree, superb explanation.

Answer (score 3):

hakre's answer illustrates well what is happening. Besides using the `END` flag you have a few more options:

- Use `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` to prevent any further rewrites. This will change after an internal redirect. See [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html#custom) for more information what is actually happening:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  RewriteRule css css.php [L,NC]
  ```
- Use `%{THE_REQUEST}` to match against the request that was made to the server. Since this does not change when you internally redirect, this can be used to prevent further redirects

  ```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /css\ HTTP
  RewriteRule ^ css.php [L,NC]
  ```
- Use a dummy variable in the query string. This would allow to prevent redirecting by defining this variable in a link, but we will use it here to prevent multiple passes:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !noredir=1
  RewriteRule css css.php?noredir=1 [L,QSA,NC]
  ```

Please note that for each of these examples you need to use this construction for each individual rule.

Comment: Another variant - but not that variable applicable - is to rewrite the rewritten URL to itself so that the no-change exit now L resolution is triggered (e.g. Apache 2.2).