# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, error-handling

My website has been slowed down a little last couple of days. I've looked into my error log and found lots of these:

```
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [error] [client 66.249.66.205] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3120): [client 66.249.66.205] r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /images/2013/02/600x376_0.076827001313237200_pixnaz_ir_1.jpg
```

---

How can I find what is causing this?

It seems a loop around index.php, with the exception of the last one which is an image, most likely linked within one of my pages (not index).

I'm using codeigniter, which is a mvc framework and everything goes trough the index.php file, so it's a bit harder to understand where it goes wrong.

Apparently it has something to do with .htaccess (it's been mentioned in couple of blogs).

Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule> 
AddType image/x-windows-bmp bmp
```

---

I did some changes to my .htaccess (basically I've removed to top conditions before the last block) and now I get this:

```
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [error] [client 66.249.74.60] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3120): [client 66.249.74.60] r->uri = /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.74.60] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.74.60] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.74.60] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.74.60] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.74.60] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.74.60] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.74.60] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.74.60] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.74.60] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php/img/images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
[Wed Oct 02 00:10:07 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.74.60] redirected from r->uri = /images/2013/07/irwm_mysite_47b49a36d251fea382ba6b494fd3532ea75c78e6.jpg
```

Now it seems there is the `img` directory in the mix, but I dont have that directory at all. There used to be a subdomain which I used for images with this address.

```
img.mysite.com => mysite.com/files/images/
```

I don't use it anymore because of some slowness and complications. Now I just use the real path to images.

Why do i get this subdomain in the loop? I don't have access to the guy who configured this server. Could it be some config / setting that he has done?

Comment: What is cuzing that is written in the log. You need to do the logging like the error message told you. Also you might want to learn about the [L] flag: [Mod_Rewrite unexpected behavior L flag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11484739/367456)

Comment: Can you adding `Options -MultiViews` on top of your .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava yes i can ... so this line , what does it do ?

Comment: This turns off problematic `MultiViews` option. Please try it out and let me know.

Comment: Did `Options -MultiViews` help?

Comment: @anubhava thanx but no i still get the error

Comment: Alright thanks for your response. Can you try commenting out `ErrorDocument 404 index.php` line (for testing only) and see if this fixed looping?

Comment: Another thing to try is adding this condition `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` just before `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]` line.

Comment: @anubhava ... this seems to be worikng ... i get lots of `file doesn't exist` now (and they are all from same address : `/public_html/img/home`) but  i dont get that looping error ... what does it do exactly ?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` does prevent looping by checking internal mod_rewrite variable `REDIRECT_STATUS` which is set to `200` after first internal redirect.

Comment: Next time you offer a bounty on a question: Please take some time formatting your question, removing txtspk like 'becuz' and '......', use capitals at the beginning of every phrase, a comma before concatenation words like 'but' and 'and' and end your phrases properly with a full stop. Even those simple things make a question soo much better.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To prevent infinite looping add an extra `RewriteCond` line on top of your rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` prevents looping by checking an internal `mod_rewrite` variable `REDIRECT_STATUS` which is set to 200 after first successful internal redirect.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Answer (score 5):

Looking to your htaccess I see that you use it to remove `index.php` from your url, but you are missing the `RewriteBase`, you can add it after the `RewriteEngine On` directly like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 
AddType image/x-windows-bmp bmp
```

So, `RewriteBase /` will be valid if your application/website is not on a `subdomain`. However, if it is then you might need to add the folder name after the `/` symbol.

Comment: thanx , i've done this before .. only difference is i get error like this `redirected from r->uri = /index.php` till the last one

Answer (score 4):

The last block:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Is most likely re-injecting a changed request URI over and over again which could cause such an internal redirect error. Check the error log with debugging level enabled to trace each redirect step, it makes things much more visible and will tell you exactly which redirect rules are triggering it.

For a detailed description and how to prevent the re-injection, please see:

- [Mod_Rewrite unexpected behavior L flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11484739/367456)

The [solution outlined there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12106419/367456) actually should do it in your case as well. It's pretty much the same, even the file-names are identical.

Comment: thanx , i'm fairly good programer but i suck at webmastering , networking , handling servers , htaccess ,  english ! ...  it seems a detailed answer is in the second link that you gave but while i'm getting hold of concepts and whats going on could you pleas simply tell me if this looping is happening for all of the link of my website or just the one that have a specific rules ... btw someone else hase wroted this htaccess , im just the programmer

Comment: For a programmer: Consider there is a while loop around that. And it does not exit unless the URL does not change any longer. As the body changes the URL everytime (it always adds `index.php?/` in front), the loop is never existed. Luckily apache gives you an error otherwise you would have ended up in an endless loop which would lock up your servers resources after some little requests.

Comment: I doubt that block is causing any problems.  The `!-f` and `!-d` conditions will prevent the last block from executing more than once (assuming index.php is an actual file, the `!-f` condition won't match and the rewrite won't happen)

Comment: You now need to add a condition to not change the URL when you already  changed it, like if it starts with `index.php?` already. This is done by: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php`, add that condition.

Comment: @Sam Dufel: Well I can't perfectly say *unless* the OP provides the debug log data which OP *still* misses to provide even the error message told otherwise and I also did in the answer and in comments. From my experience when such errors occur, it's most likely missing to see that the L flat is not the last resort. For a quick solution without trouble-shooting the concrete configuration on the concrete server, most often a check if the server supports the END flag can resolve this in a hard exit without further dealings if available.

Comment: @hakre - it sounds more likely there's an error somewhere in the application layer on a particular page.  If those rules in the htaccess were actually looping, every page except index.php would die with a 500 error.

Comment: @hakre would you pleas tell me where can i find/enable `LogLevel` .. i've red  the document in here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel ... i know i should add `LogLevel debug` to some config file ... but i cant find out where .

Comment: It's worth noting that all the work (intended to be) done by the mod_rewrite block can be more economically done by the 404 handler as specified in the !mod_rewrite block

Comment: @SamDufel: *"10 internal redirects"* - please take notice of the word *"internal"* in front of redirects. That are those by mod_rewrite without passing the request to the application. The external redirect loops are normally detected by the browser, not the server.

Comment: @max: The config-file you're looking for is the one from the webserver. It's in this field: *"Context: server config, virtual host"*, that means either in the server configuration file or inside your virtual host config. Contact your system administrator for those sections.

Comment: @hakre thanx i did it , also i've replaced to old error with new ones . as you said it seems a loop around index.php , with the exeption of last one which is an image , most likely linked within one of my pages (not index)

Comment: There is a directive called `RewriteBase`. Read a little about it and choose the right value for your setup. It might already solve your issue. If not, introduce the index.php check I linked since the beginning. The rewrite log seems to confirm my first assumption which rule is causing this. You can also find out by commenting it out for trouble shooting.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [END flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end), instead of the L flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [END]
```

> Using the [END] flag terminates not only the current round of rewrite processing (like [L]) but also prevents any subsequent rewrite processing from occurring in per-directory (htaccess) context.
>
> This does not apply to new requests resulting from external redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a dummie awnser, but I just empty my .htaccess and configure permalinks again. Everything works after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had some performance issues in Apache when the loglevel was debug ... Moving back to Error mode speedup the requests

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the "RewriteBase /drupal" in my .htaccess file  present in drupal root folder. It works for me.