# Is it possible to change a subdomain's directory with .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an image sharing website and I used to have a sub-domain for the images, however I had to delete it, so now I use a real path to the images:

**old url:**

```
http://img.site.com/images/2013/03/abc.jpg
```

**new url:**

```
http://site.com/files/images/2013/03/abc.jpg
```

The problem with this is that I have a lot of images linked from other websites and search engines that are still using the old URL.

The problem with the old sub-domain is that it's directory (`public_html/files`) and its name (`img.`) are different, so special configuration was needed to handle that and I got tired of all the problems that it was causing.

Now I have created a normal `img.` sub-domain that is pointing to the `public_html/img` directory so that no extra configuration needed, however my images are still in the  `public_html/files` directory.

I figure all I have to do now is replace the new directory with the old one using .htacess somehow. I don't know if this is possible.

My `.htaccess` is currently:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\.site\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(images/.*)$ http://site.com/files/images/$1[R=301,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

When I try to call an image from a subdomain I get:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /files/images/2013/10/15c100d1da3216850d6cceb4ce57eaab6d26fc92.jpg was not found on this server.
img.site.com
```

My error log reports:

```
[Mon Oct 21 02:58:46 2013] [error] [client 85.185.229.221] script '/home/site/domains/site.com/public_html/img/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: Can you enable `RewriteLog` and post the logs here.

Comment: Also `RewriteRule ^(images/.*)$ http://site.com/files/images/$1[R=301,NC,L]` needs some correction as `RewriteRule ^(images/.+)$ http://site.com/files/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`. Do make sure you're using a new browser to test it.

Comment: @anubhava i've tried to enable `RewriteLog ` in `httpd.conf` by changing `Loglevel Warn` to `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` as it was suggested here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html .... but when i restart apache i get an error `/sbin/service httpd restart 2>&1` apparently it doesn't work or i'm doing something wrong

Comment: See this link for enabling rewrite log: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite Also did you try suggested rule above in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect to the right place. In the htaccess file in your `public_html/img` directory do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://site.com/files/images/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or just

```
Redirect 301 /images http://site.com/files/images
```

Comment: is there any way to include subdomain in the rule ? there are lots of other `images` directory in my subdirectories  (in `assets` directory for example ) and using this rule would mess them up . i've tried to change `^images/(.*)$` to `^site.com/images/(.*)$` but its didn't work

Comment: if you have dedicated vhost for domain img.site.com, you can add above Redirect to vhost, not to .htacces, then it will be apllied only for requests to img.site.com/images not for all */images

Comment: @max You can include the subdomain by using the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable in a conditional match (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

Ok try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\.your-domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /files/images/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanx , i've updated my htacc and added the result at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Your modified .htaccess would look like *(assuming its placed at document root `/`)*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\.site\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(images/.*)$ http://site.com/files/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The `RewriteCond` first checks the domain and if it's the old one `img.site.com`, redirects any `/images` requests to the new URL.

Comment: Yes, I'm going through it as we speak.

Comment: also check this out , maybe it has something to do with this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071324/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects .... thanx again

Comment: (1) Is your htaccess inside `/public_html`? (2) Make sure there's a space between `$ [R=301,NC,L]` (3) Is the file you're trying to access as `http://img.site.com/images/2013/10/image.jpg` accessible when you go to `http://site.com/files/images/2013/10/image.jpg`?

Comment: 1 - yes , 2 - it is , 3- yes

Comment: I think whatever config your cpanel does when you create a subdomain is interfering with the htaccess rules. If you have wildcard dns enabled (i.e. `*.site.com` points to `site.com`) you would be able to reach your site's main page from `anything.site.com` as well. Can you try setting up the `htaccess` rules for `images.site.com` instead and see if the files become accessible? Basically, I want to pull any server config that's forcing `img.site.com` to go through `/img` out of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

well I can provide an indirect solution where you have to make a little changes in your header or footer files, and for that, type below lines in your .htaccess,

```
HeaderName /path/.../header.html (if .html) or if .php header then,

AddType text/html .php
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .php
HeaderName /path/.../header.php
```

or simply ReadmeName /path/.../footer.html for footer, 
then use copy+unlink (for moving files but slow one), (or precisely rename() would be a better option), in that file for your task.