# Bluehost: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, bluehost

I have deployed a website which was built using **django** within **bluehost**. I can access all urls(like "/home", "/products/") and I get the webpages fine without any error. But when I try to access the API of the website, I get error 500:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@abc.com and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have used django-rest-framework here.
I have checked the error log, its like this:  **Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.**

my .htaccess is like this:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi <br>
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ demo.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

my fcgi file is like this:

```
 #!/home3/env/python27/bin/python27
    import sys, os
    # Add a custom Python path.
    sys.path.insert(0, "/env/python27")
    sys.path.insert(13, "/public_html/tcm/hyy/app")
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings'
    from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
    runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

How can I solve this problem? 
PS: I have seen this solution but its not working: [Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071324/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting for any future sufferers:

Make sure your `.htaccess` file is in the `/home#/username/public_html` directory. Moving mine from `/home#/username` solved this problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I can't verify your answer right now, so when I will do that, I will accept your answer :)