# Redirecting all urls (including existing files) to the same page results in a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is  my current `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule (.*)(/|\\)$ $1 [R]

# everything
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /handler.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, this doesn't work, it throws a `500 Internal Server Error`
My previous `.htaccess` file looked like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)(/|\\)$ $1 [R]

# everything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /handler.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And it worked, except for specific files. However, now I'd like the specific files to redirect into the handler as well. Is there a way to use `RewriteRule`s without the `RewriteCond`s?

Comment: With the first version you are getting “an error”, because it causes a redirect loop – `handler.php` itself matches `^(.*?)$`, and so your request gets rewritten over and over and over again. What you want is a `RewriteCond` that only checks if the REQUEST_FILENAME is not `handler.php`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071324/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects

Comment: That was the problem, thanks, you guys!! I didn't realise that Rewriting loops around to be `.htaccess`'d again. Do you want to write this as the answer or should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) and [Sumurai8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2209007/sumurai8), I was able to fix the problem on my own. The problem was not that you can't have `RewriteRule`s without `RewriteCond`s, but that if you rewrite every url into a single file, it will rewrite requests to that specific file to itself once more, creating an infinite loop.

The new `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule (.*)(/|\\)$ $1 [R,L]

# everything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/handler.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /handler.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Relevant resource: [Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071324/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since title says **With .htaccess, is it possible to not have RewriteCond?**

Comment: Moreover answer is **wrong** due to use of `REQUEST_FILENAME` in it. It will still cause 500 error.

Comment: It does not work because `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/handler.php$` condition is wrong and will always fail.

Comment: I'm literally using it on my site and it is working.

Comment: I have tested it **exactly** as is and it caused 500.

Comment: Maybe I have a strange configuration. I see, it's usually `REQUEST_URI`, isn't it? I'll update the answer to use that instead.

Comment: Yes with `REQUEST_URI` it will work (I have removed my downvote now). But still it is not an answer to your own question, you asked an answer without `RewriteCond` and that's where my answer will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without `RewriteCond` for file check you can tweak your regex like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# remove trailing slash for non directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R,L]

# every request not for handler.php
RewriteRule ^((?!handler\.php$).*)$ handler.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This didn't fix the problem and you changed my rules in ways that I didn't want.

Comment: I was updating the rule when your comment came. Try it now and tell me which rule got changed.